# Selenium WD - southwest.com

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am constantly getting "No Such Element Exception" for "First Name" test box

Below is my code:

```
public class southwestSignUpSave {
WebDriver oBrw;

@Before
public void loadwebsite (){
    oBrw = new FirefoxDriver();
    oBrw.manage().window().maximize();
    oBrw.get("https://southwest.com");
    oBrw.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}

@Test
public void signUpAndSave(){

    oBrw.findElement(By.partialLinkText("OFFERS")).click(); 
    oBrw.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Sign")).click();
    //oBrw.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    WebDriverWait oWait = new WebDriverWait(oBrw, 30);
   oWait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("FIRST_NAME")));

    oBrw.findElement(By.id("FIRST_NAME")).clear();
    oBrw.findElement(By.id("FIRST_NAME")).sendKeys("abc");
    oBrw.findElement(By.id("LAST_NAME")).clear();
    oBrw.findElement(By.id("LAST_NAME")).sendKeys("asd");
    oBrw.findElement(By.id("EMAIL")).clear();
    oBrw.findElement(By.id("EMAIL")).sendKeys("abc@asd.com");
    new Select(oBrw.findElement(By.id("HOME_AIRPORT"))).selectByVisibleText("Akron/Canton, OH - CAK");
    oBrw.findElement(By.id("IAN")).click();


}
```

}

I tried to use id and name.

where am I going wrong. I am new to Selenium WD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can try finding the element using xpath. For that u need to install the firepath plugin in firefox and then inspect the element using firepath.

```
oBrw.findElement(By.xpath("copy paste the xpath here")).clear();
```

I would also recommend loading the driver using System property inside loadwebsite() method.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.driver", "//your driver path");
oBrw=new FirefoxDriver();
```

if the Sign page opens in a new tab/window then u need to navigate to that tab/window because Selenium by default stays in the opening tab. To navigate u need to add the following lines of code after clicking on "Sign"-

```
Set<String> s=wd.getWindowHandles();
Iterator<String> it=s.iterator();
it.next();//control goes to 1st default tab
String str=it.next().toString();//control goes to the next tab
oBrw.switchTo().window(str);//driver switches to the new window/tab.
```

if the element is present inside a frame then also u need to switch to that frame first before finding element inside it. Below is the code-

```
WebElement web=oBrw.findElement(By.xpath("copy paste your frame xpath"));
oBrw.switchTo.frame(web);
```

now try to find the element present in the new tab/window.

Answer (score 0):

That Text box is inside an iFrame, so you need to switch to that iFrame first then try findElement method to locate textbox.

```
oBrw.findElement(By.partialLinkText("OFFERS")).click(); 
            oBrw.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Sign")).click();

            oBrw.switchTo().defaultContent();
            oBrw.switchTo().frame(0);           
            WebElement id = oBrw.findElement(By.name("FIRST_NAME"));
            id.sendKeys("USERNAME");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes this works.. just one more questions, oBrw.switchTo().frame(0)

Comment: what parameter you looked for "0" in frame(0)

Answer (score 0):

FIRST NAME input text field is inside `iframe`. Check the below piece of HTML.

```html
<iframe frameborder="0" src="https://luv.southwest.com/servlet/formlink/f?kOHpjQACAY" onload="scroll(0,0);" verticalscrolling="no" horizontalscrolling="no" scrolling="no" title="Click 'n Save signup form"></iframe>
<html dir="ltr">

<head>

  <body>
    <p>
      <span class="required">*Required</span>
    </p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <form id="cnsForm" onsubmit="return validateForm();" action="https://luv.southwest.com/servlet/campaignrespondent" method="POST">
      <div class="form_field first_name">
        <label for="first_name">
          <input id="FIRST_NAME" type="text"=""="" maxlength="25" size="22" name="FIRST_NAME">
      </div>
...
```

Hence selenium is unable to find out the element. Here we need to explicitly switch to iframe as below. Insert below code snippet before you find FIRST_NAME. (You can insert well formatted xpath of iframe. I just grabbed it from firebug.)

```
 WebElement iframeSwitch = oBrw.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div[3]/iframe"));
            oBrw.switchTo().frame(iframeSwitch);
```